# Coordinate multiple threads after N executions

Tags: java, multithreading, groovy, concurrency, synchronization

I have a Java/Groovy multi threaded process that I want to "synchronize" after N executions:
- a shared counter is decremented after each thread execution
- the goal is to reset the counter once it reaches 0 while no other thread is accessing it.

I tried with a [ReadWriteReentrantLock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html) but it looks I have a race condition for the decrement phase. Here is my test code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(Decrementer.MAX_SIZE)
    ReadWriteLock lock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock()

    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        Decrementer d = new Decrementer(counter, lock)
        new Thread(d).start()
    }
}

public class Decrementer implements Runnable {

    public final static int MAX_SIZE = 5
    private ReadWriteLock lock
    private AtomicInteger counter

    public Decrementer(AtomicInteger counter, ReadWriteLock lock) {
        this.counter = counter
        this.lock = lock
    }

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try{
                lock.readLock().lock()
                int current = this.counter.decrementAndGet()
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " at counter " + current)
                Thread.sleep(762)
            } finally {
                lock.readLock().unlock()
            }

            try {
                lock.writeLock().lock()
                int current = this.counter.get()
                if (current <= 0) {
                    this.counter.set(Decrementer.MAX_SIZE)
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " reset " + current + " to " + Decrementer.MAX_SIZE)
                    Thread.sleep(4217)
                }
            } finally {
                lock.writeLock().unlock()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which give the following weird output (with negative counter value), probably due to a missing "synchronized" check of the AtomicInteger value.

```
Thread-3 at counter 2
Thread-2 at counter 4
Thread-1 at counter 3
Thread-4 at counter 1
Thread-5 at counter 0
Thread-6 at counter -1
Thread-7 at counter -2
Thread-8 at counter -3
Thread-9 at counter -4
Thread-10 at counter -5
Thread-2 reset -5 to 5
Thread-3 at counter 4
Thread-4 at counter 2
Thread-2 at counter 3
Thread-1 at counter 1
Thread-5 at counter -3
Thread-10 at counter -4
Thread-7 at counter -1
Thread-6 at counter -2
Thread-8 at counter 0
Thread-9 at counter -5
Thread-9 reset -5 to 5
```

I also saw [CountDownLatch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) and [CyclicBarrier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html) classes but my goal is not to sync all threads but to ensure the counter reset is atomic and excluding other modification by other threads.

Do you see any obvious concurrency issue I missed in my code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your lock is vise versa. You're acquiring read lock, then doing "write". This should work:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(Decrementer.MAX_SIZE);
    ReadWriteLock lock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();

    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        Decrementer d = new Decrementer(counter, lock);
        new Thread(d).start();
    }
}

static public class Decrementer implements Runnable {

    public final static int MAX_SIZE = 5;
    private ReadWriteLock lock;
    private AtomicInteger counter;

    public Decrementer(AtomicInteger counter, ReadWriteLock lock) {
        this.counter = counter;
        this.lock = lock;
    }

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                lock.writeLock().lock();
                int current = this.counter.decrementAndGet();
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " at counter " + current);
                if (current <= 0) {
                    this.counter.set(Decrementer.MAX_SIZE);
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " reset " + current + " to " + Decrementer.MAX_SIZE);
                    Thread.sleep(4217);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                lock.writeLock().unlock();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. You're quite right: I was doing a write (to the counter) in the read lock.
But in your solution you try to acquire a WriteLock for each thread, which will quickly lead to starvation (only 1 thread running at a time actually)
I'll followup your advice and group the write part (decrement+test+reset counter together) and keep the read lock for the process (simulated by Sleep)

Comment: This was just a working example, not a full solution. I also strongly discourage of using Thread.sleep(4217) in production! :)

Answer (score 0):

based on the write lock acquire comment, here is working solution:

```
public class Decrementer implements Runnable {

public final static int MAX_SIZE = 20;
private ReadWriteLock lock;
private AtomicInteger counter;

public Decrementer(AtomicInteger counter, ReadWriteLock lock) {
    this.counter = counter;
    this.lock = lock;
}

public void run() {

    while (true) {
        int current
        try {
            lock.writeLock().lock();
            if (this.counter.compareAndSet(0, Decrementer.MAX_SIZE)) {
                current = 0;
                flushWork(current);
            } else {
                current = counter.decrementAndGet();
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " decrement  " + current);
            }
        } finally {
            lock.writeLock().unlock();
        }

        try {
            lock.readLock().lock();
            doWork(current);
        } finally {
            lock.readLock().unlock();
        }
    }
}

private void flushWork(int current) {
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " reset " + current + " to " + Decrementer.MAX_SIZE);
    System.out.println('------------------------------------------------------------------------------------');
    Thread.sleep(4217);
}

private void doWork(int current) {
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " at counter " + current);
    Thread.sleep(62);
}
}
```